# Find the orthogonal basis of $ \ C (A) \ \ and \ \ R(A) \ $

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 8 & 2 \end{bmatrix}. Find the orthogonal basis of $   \ C (A) \ \ and \ \ R(A) \ $. $$ $$ To find the orthogonal basis of the the column space C(A) of the matrix A  , we have to use Gram-Schimdt process . But the columns of the matrix are not linearly independent and so they do not form a basis. **Then how can I apply Gram-Schimdt method to basis to find orthogonal basis ?**

Answer (score 1):

Colunms, are 4 vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ so are dipendent ad you said. To apply gram-schmidt algorithm you need to find 3 of them that form a basis(supposing $rk(A)=3$) or 2 of them that form a basis( if $rk(A)=2$)
In this case clearly the first and second colunm, $\{v_1;v_2\}$ form a basis, so you Just Need to apply the algorithm to them, so you have:
$e_1=\frac{v_1}{||v_1||}$ and then 
$e_2=\frac{v_2-<v_2,e_1>e_1}{||v_2-<v_2,e_1>e_1||}$ and $\{e_1;e_2\}$ will be the basis you are searching for

Comment: But rank of A=2 .  No three columns are linearly independent. So how can I assume a basis?

Comment: I edited the answer, have a look

Comment: Well in that case , clearly the 1st and 2nd columns are linearly independent. so they form a basis . Then what I do? Would  you show  a little more work ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Gram-Schmidt and keep only the nonzero vectors you get.

Alternatively, determine a basis beforehand. Do Gaussian elimination:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 8 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -5 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -5 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This tells you that
$$
\left\{\;
\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix},\;
\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}\;
\right\}
$$
is a basis for $C(A)$ and also provides you a basis of $R(A)$.

Now apply Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: So I will have to apply gram -Schimdt method on this basis of C(A) obtained above  only.  Right ?

Comment: Would you be more explicit about the 2nd case , i.e., the basis of R(A)  with an basis ? Thank you

Comment: @mabmath Yes, for the first. A basis of $R(A)$ is formed by the nonzero rows in the echelon form.